# Converting Image in png format to vector format using Sketch (Mac)

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, sketch-3

I am new to sketch and I am facing some issues in generating Vectors for some of the icons which I have in .png format.

Could any one please refer some tutorial or tell me some simple way to get through this.

Feel free to guide me if I am wrong somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: Have you googled for it? What have you done so far?

Comment: I have googled it , and some of the links which I browsed had some third party software links which again links to some adware sites , So I am in a bit of confusion whether I should go for those apps or not.

Comment: you can try https://vectormagic.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Himanshu,

I also faced same issues but I think there is no such easy way to get out of this using Sketch.

but still, you can review this basic Youtube tutorial for the same.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKT8pDVrYtY

Hope this helps you out buddy.

Happy designing.

Comment: Thanks for helping out but some of the icons which I am using are way too complex , I think now I have to move back to Photoshop.

But thanks for helping out Mate.

Answer (score 4):

Sketch is very useful but it is also limited on its vector capabilities. The function you are looking for is called Live Tracing, you can find it on Illustrator and it is very acurate if your icon is in high contrast or transparent background. You could trace it manually but that can take a long time for complex shapes, and not as accurate.

Inkscape might be a good free option for this. Should be good enough if the pngs are not too detailed.